# For Loop in pandas only outputs last iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple Python code that loops i times to search for a table on a site and exports to an Excel sheet. The problem is that I only see the last iteration of the loop and not the rest. Does anyone know how to get the rest of the loop results on to Excel?

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r"c:\temp\test.html"
path = open(filename, 'r')
destination = r"c:\users\someone\desktop\test.xlsx"

table = pd.io.html.read_html(filename, attrs= {'class':'table'})

num_tables = (len(table))

for i in range(0, num_tables):

    tables = table[i]

print(tables)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(destination, engine='xlsxwriter')
dfi.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Test')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Test']

writer.save()
```

Comment: Because your `print` is outside the `for` loop

Comment: Hi Roganjosh, thanks for the comment. Actually, even if print(tables) is within the for loop, it doesn't reflect on Excel as it only saves the last iteration. Sorry, I just started Python and programming in general so almost have no clue..

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the ExcelWriter instance before the loop. Then use `to_excel` inside loop. Finally, save the writer at the end of the script (as you have).

You should set the sheet_name to a variable that changes on very loop to ensure that you end up with an excel file with many sheets, rather than overwriting the 'test' sheet.

**Update**

Perhaps you are looking for something like the below. Its difficult to know without seeing an example of the data. This assumes that the dataframes from the website are all in the same format.

```
list_of_frames = pd.io.html.read_html(filename, attrs= {'class':'table'})
df = pd.concat(list_of_frames)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for your comment. This really helps. I don't want to create new sheets on every loop but to stack them on each loop in the same sheet. Your method does work but it seems like it's missing a few data for reasons I do not know.....

Comment: In that case you should start an empty list. Then loop through appending DataFrames to the list. At the end, use concatenate the list of DataFrames and export this new, concatenated DataFrames to excel. No need to create an excelwriter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've tried your method. I seems like its obtains the last table but misses a few rows in other tables. print(dfi) seems to work but I need to export it to Excel....